# How to start IPython notebook remotely?

Tags: ssh, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Following these instructions ([Running a notebook server](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/public_server.html#) and [Remote access to IPython Notebooks](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh)
) I proceed as follows:

On the remote server:

1) Setting NotebookApp.password()

```
In [1]: from IPython.lib import passwd
In [2]: passwd()    
Enter password:
Verify password:
Out[2]: 'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'
```

2) Create profile

```
user@remote_host$ ipython profile create
```

3) Edit `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_notebook_config.py`

```
# Password to use for web authentication
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.password =
u'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'
```

4) Start notebook on port 8889

```
user@remote_host$ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

and the notebook starts

> [I 16:08:10.012 NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN:https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
>
> [W 16:08:10.131 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'terminado')
>
> [I 16:08:10.132 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /cluster/home/user
>
> [I 16:08:10.132 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
>
> [I 16:08:10.132 NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8889/
>
> [I 16:08:10.132 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).

On my local machine

5) SSH tunneling

```
 user@local$ ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:127.0.0.1:8889 username@remote_host
```

On the remote host (`/etc/hosts`) you find

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

6) Finally, I try to open `localhost:8888` on my browser, and I get:

> channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
>
> channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
>
> channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
>
> channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
>
> channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

All these steps work on one server, but fail on another one.

I tried contacting the administrator and said the following:

> I assume that you are using two separate SSH connections: one from
>   which you run ipython and one that you use to do port forwarding.
>   There is no guarantee that the two connections will land you on the
>   same login node. In the case where the two connections are on
>   different hosts, you will experience the exact failure you have
>   encountered. Therefore you should setup the port forwarding in the
>   connection that you use to run ipython.

How can I setup the port forwarding in the connection that I use to run ipython?

I tried using my ip address but it didn't work

```
$ ssh -N -f -L local_ip_address:8888:127.0.0.1:8889 user@remote_host
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally this is how the problem was solved:

```
# Login to the server from your local workstation and in the same connection do the port forwarding.
user@local$ ssh -L 8888:localhost:8889 username@remote_host
user@remote_host$ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Comment: the final line should read:

`user@remote_host$ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8888`

then is works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this instruction.

https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh